# I wanted to install the PIP module on the server but i cant install anything on the server as I do not have root access to it

Tags: python

```
I wanted to install the PIP module on the server but i cant install anything on the server 

as I do not have root access to it ..
```

Support suggested -
You cannot (and we will not) use "pip" to install them into the system Python directories. You will need to manually build and install it into your build directories in your development server and then package it with your code.

Instructions for separating the python "build" step from the "install" step can be obtained from wherever you got the module.

Here are some instructions on the Python website that may be useful:

https://docs.python.org/2.7/install/index.html#alternate-installation-the-user-scheme

Comment: Create and activate a virtual environment. Install into your virtual env.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a virtual environment and install your packages there

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html